# first fstream program

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program that gets data from this text file:
[image]

Then, based on this data, the program is supposed to calculate the average gpa of each gender (f=female, m=male) and output the results in a new file.

It must also contain these five functions:

**openFiles**: this function opens the input and output files and sets the output of floating-point numbers to two decimal places in a fixed decimal format with a decimal point and trailing zeros.

**initialize**: this function initializes variables.

**sumGrades**: This function finds the sum of the female and male students GPAs.

**average grade**: This function finds the average GPA for male and female students.

**printResults**: this function outputs the relevent results.

I think I've done pretty good coding up the functions and all but since this is my first program using fstream im not sure how i need to implement them in my main function.

Here is what i have so far:

**header**:

```
#ifndef header_h
#define header_h

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void extern initialize(int&, int&, float&, float&);
void extern openFiles(ifstream, ofstream);
void extern sumGrades(ifstream, ofstream, char, float, int&, int&, float&, float&);
void averageGrade (float&, float&, float, int, float, int);
void extern printResults (float, float, ofstream);



#endif
```

**main**:

```
#include "header.h"


int main()
{
    char gender;
    float gpa, sumFemaleGPA, sumMaleGPA;
    ifstream inData;
    ofstream outData;
    int countFemale, countMale;



    inData.open("./Ch7_Ex4Data.txt");
    outData.open("./Ch7_Ex4Dataout.txt");

    do
    inData >> gender >> gpa;
    while(!inData.eof());




    inData.close();
    outData.close();

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**openFiles**:

```
#include "header.h"

void openFiles(ifstream inData, ofstream outData)
{

    inData.open("./Ch7_Ex4Data.txt");
    outData.open("./Ch7_Ex4Dataout.txt");

    outData << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2); 

    inData.close();
    outData.close();

}
```

**sumGrades**:

```
#include "header.h"

void sumGrades(ifstream inData, ofstream outData, char gender, float gpa, int& countFemale, int& countMale, float& sumFemaleGPA, 
               float& sumMaleGPA)
{
     char m, f;

    do
    {

     inData >> gender >> gpa;

           if(gender == m)
              {
                         sumMaleGPA += gpa;
                         countMale++;   
              }         

     else if (gender == f)
              {
                      sumFemaleGPA += gpa;
                      countFemale++;
              }
    }
    while(!inData.eof());
}
```

**averageGrade**:

```
#include "header.h"

void averageGrade (float& maleGrade, float& femaleGrade, float sumMaleGPA, int countMale, float sumFemaleGPA, int countFemale)
{
     maleGrade = sumMaleGPA / static_cast<float>(countMale);

     femaleGrade = sumFemaleGPA / static_cast<float>(countFemale);
}
```

**printResults**:

```
#include "header.h"

void
{
     outData << "average male GPA: " << maleGrade << endl;
     outData << "average female GPA: " << femaleGrade << endl;    
}
```

Comment: What's your question? What is your current code doing? Are there compiler errors, or is it misbehaving? Is this homework? If so it should be tagged as such.

Comment: You don't need static_cast in `averageGrade`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making good progress.

You don't need the `static_cast`s in `averageGrade`.

`printResults` is missing most of its function signature.

In `sumGrades`, `gpa` and `gender` should be local variables, not parameters.  You also want to compare to the character literals `'m'` and `'f'`, not variables named `m` and `f` with random contents.

Streams should ALWAYS be passed by reference, they can't be copied.

[When reading from a stream, you should test the stream itself in your while loop, not `eof()`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/730910/103167)

Did you have a question?

Comment: i will complete you since i'm bit lazy to write my answer : the loop in main() always assings to the same variables (and do nothing in it)

Comment: functions are defined but never used

Comment: @pastjean: `main` is just a mess, clearly it's supposed to call the other functions.

Answer (score 2):

You must pass the file streams by non-const references:

```
void extern openFiles(ifstream&, ofstream&);
```

`sumGrades` and `printResults` don't care that these streams are files, so you can pass just streams, still these must be references:

```
void extern sumGrades(istream&, ostream&, char, float, int&, int&, float&, float&);
void extern printResults (float, float, ostream&);
```

`averageGrade` is missing `extern`.

```
void extern averageGrade (float&, float&, float, int, float, int);
```

`openFiles` does nothing useful. It opens files and closes them... You shouldn't close them:

```
void openFiles(ifstream& inData, ofstream& outData) {
    inData.open("./Ch7_Ex4Data.txt");
    outData.open("./Ch7_Ex4Dataout.txt");

    outData << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2); 
    // leave them open    
}
```

The point is that you should call these function to open the files from `main`:

```
// in main():
ifstream inData;
ofstream outData;

openFiles(inData, outData);
// call other functions to do the task.
// pass inData and outData as above, where stream arguments are expected.
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Don;t do this:

```
do
{
    inData >> gender >> gpa;
    STUFF
} while(!inData.eof());
```

If it fails to read gender or gpa it still does stuff.
Wchich means that that the last line of your file was processed twice.

A better way to write this is:

```
while( inData >> gender >> gpa )
{
     STUFF
}
```

Now STUFF is only done if gender and gpa are correctly read from the file.

This if statement is not required.

```
      if(gender == m)
          {
                     sumMaleGPA += gpa;
                     countMale++;   
          }         

 else if (gender == f)
          {
                  sumFemaleGPA += gpa;
                  countFemale++;
          }
```

You can use a map (or other container to hold these values). That way your code is more readable (and when we get a new third species easier to expand).

```
std::map<char, std::pair<double, int> >   data;

std::pair<int,int>&  value = data[gender];
value.first += gpa;    // First contains the total gpa for a gender
value.second++;        // Second contains the count of a gender.
```

Looks like this:

```
void readData(std::istream& in, std::map<char, std::pair<double,int> >& data)
{
        char    gender;
        double  gpa;
        while(inData >> gender >> gpa)
        {
            data[gender].first  += gpa;
            data[gender].second ++;
        }
}
//
// Notice that we pass streams by reference.
// Also notice that it is a generic stream not a file stream.
// This function does not need to know the output is going to a file
// so you can now re-use it to print to another type of stream std::cout
void writeData(std::ostream& out, std::map<char, std::pair<double,int> >& data)
{
    for(std::map<char, std::pair<double,int> >::const_iterator loop = data.begin();
        loop != data.end();
        ++loop
       )
    {
        char                  gender = loop->first;
        std::pair<double,int> value  = loop->second;

        out << gender << ": " << value.first / value.second << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
        std::map<char, std::pair<double,int> >  data;

        std::ifstream                           inData("./Ch7_Ex4Data.txt");
        readData(inData, data);

        std::ofstream                           outData("./Ch7_Ex4Dataout.txt");
        writeData(outData, data);

        // Don;t bother to close the files.
        // This happens automatically when the file goes out of scope.
        //
        // Genereally you use close() manually when you want to catch a problem that
        // is happening when you close the file. Since even if you did find a problem
        // there is nothing you can do with the problem don;t do it.
        //
        // Also note: potentially close() can throw an exception.
        // If you let the file close automatically with the destructor (it calls close
        // catches the exception and throws it away).
}
```

Answer (score -1):

printResults must not have copied correctly. I suspect it must have the signature

```
void printResults(float maleGrade, float femaleGrad);
```

When you are reading your file you need to see if the gender is m or f then branch and add the next GPA to the gender GPA.

something like

```
if(gender == "m"){
   maleGPA += gpa;
   maleCount++;
}
else{
   femaleGPA += gpa;
    femaleCount++;
}
// Call the next functions you copy pasted from your homework assignment
```

Comment: Comparing to a string literal will not have the desired effect.