# check my logic? (average gpa calculating program)

Tags: c++

program reads the following data from a .txt file:

```
f   3.40
f   4.00
m   3.56
m   3.80
f   2.30
f   3.95
m   3.90
m   4.00
m   2.00
f   4.00
f   2.80
m   3.70
m   2.98
f   3.89
m   4.00
f   3.90
m   1.90
m   2.90
f   1.50
f   2.67
m   3.80
m   2.35
```

Then calculates the average (gpa) for each gender (m for male, f for female)

according to my calculations there are:

14 fs, the sum of gpas for f is 46.99, so the average gpa for f is 46.99/14 = 3.36.

and

14 ms, the sum of gpas for m is 46.64, so the average gpa for m is 46.64/14 = 3.33.

but what the program outputs in a new file is:
average male GPA: 3.42
average female GPA: 3.76

Am i missing something in my operations?

my code:

**header**:

```
#ifndef header_h
#define header_h
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
void extern initialize(int&, int&, float&, float&, float&, float&);
void extern openFiles(ifstream&, ofstream&);
void extern sumGrades(istream&, ostream&, int&, int&, float&, float&);
void extern averageGrade (float&, float&, float, int, float, int);
void extern printResults (float, float, ostream&);
#endif
```

**main**:

```
#include "header.h"
int main()
{
    char gender;
    float gpa, sumFemaleGPA, sumMaleGPA, maleGrade, femaleGrade;
    ifstream inData;
    ofstream outData;
    int countFemale, countMale;

    openFiles(inData, outData);
    initialize (countFemale, countMale, sumFemaleGPA, sumMaleGPA, maleGrade, femaleGrade);
    sumGrades(inData, outData, countFemale, countMale, sumFemaleGPA, sumMaleGPA);
    averageGrade (maleGrade, femaleGrade, sumMaleGPA, countMale, sumFemaleGPA, countFemale);
    printResults(maleGrade, femaleGrade, outData); 


    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**openFiles**:

```
    #include "header.h"

    void openFiles(ifstream& inData, ofstream& outData)
    {

    inData.open("./Ch7_Ex4Data.txt");
    outData.open("./Ch7_Ex4Dataout.txt");

    outData << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);        
}
```

**initialize**:

```
#include "header.h"

void initialize (int& countFemale, int& countMale, float& sumFemaleGPA, float& sumMaleGPA, float& maleGrade, float& femaleGrade)
{
            countFemale = 0;
            countMale = 0;
            sumFemaleGPA = 0;
            sumMaleGPA = 0;
            maleGrade = 0;
            femaleGrade = 0;
}
```

**sumGrades**:

```
#include "header.h"

void sumGrades(istream& inData, ostream& outData, int& countFemale, int& countMale, float& sumFemaleGPA, 
               float& sumMaleGPA)
{

     char gender;
     float gpa;

   while( inData >> gender >> gpa )
    {

     inData >> gender >> gpa;

           if(gender == 'm')
              {
                         sumMaleGPA += gpa;
                         countMale++;   
              }         

     else if (gender == 'f')
              {
                      sumFemaleGPA += gpa;
                      countFemale++;
              }
    }

}
```

**averageGrade**:

```
#include "header.h"

void averageGrade (float& maleGrade, float& femaleGrade, float sumMaleGPA, int countMale, float sumFemaleGPA, int countFemale)
{
     maleGrade = sumMaleGPA / countMale;

     femaleGrade = sumFemaleGPA / countFemale;
}
```

**printResults**:

```
#include "header.h"

void printResults(float maleGrade, float femaleGrade, ostream& outData) 
{
     outData << "average male GPA: " << maleGrade << endl;
     outData << "average female GPA: " << femaleGrade << endl;    
}
```

Comment: I think you're trying a little too hard to cut things up into multiple files, and not hard enough to either use return values properly, or try your hand at designing some classes.

Comment: Don't declare all the variabels at the top. Declare (and initialize) them as they about to be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't these lines: skip every other line:

```
while( inData >> gender >> gpa )
{
  inData >> gender >> gpa;
```

You're using the return of the >> operator to indicate success for the test of the while loop, but each time it executes that, does it not consume that line and move to the next, so then when you execute it again inside the while loop you effectively overwrite the data from line 1 with the data from line 2 and ignore line 1.

Comment: That what i used initially but this other way was suggested to me as being better. see the answer to my previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479504/first-fstream-program/4479587#4479587

Comment: Okay, I did some more research and I guess what happens is that the ifstream is cast to a pointer when used as the test in a while loop, if the failbit is set (which occurs when you attempt to read past EOF) it returns null which is the same as false. So yes, that usage is fine.

Comment: Oh and this site: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/ is great, BTW.

Comment: I wish we could -1 comments at times like this. `if (stream >> foo)` (and similarly with 'while') is not only fine and designed for, but idiomatic. Testing `while (!stream.eof())` is, in most cases, exactly what you **don't** want to do, because `.eof()` doesn't return true until *after there has been a failed attempt* - the practical result, in most cases, is that you process the last item twice. See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.4 for more.

Comment: No need to get bent out of shape @Karl, we got on the right track. The fact that the `if (stream >> foo)` functionality is made to work using an implicit cast to void* makes it somewhat unintuitive for someone new to the ifstream class and looking at the documentation. But thank you for the link, I'm sure it will be helpful.

Comment: "someone new to the ifstream class" shouldn't care about the details; and, for a language like C++, really ought to be given a better way to figure out what to do - let alone what's idiomatic - than reading the documentation. :) (I'm also not mad or anything - I just come across **really** matter-of-fact on the internet, especially when there's a risk that someone could possibly pick up a bad programming habit...)